Child container is not filling all height parent container with display flex and scroll
I have a problem with CSS which I don't get solved. I have one parent container called plcRemoteFormContainer with one child container <form id="plcRemoteForm">. This child should meet the next requirements:

Be centered.
Fill the entire height of parent container
Display scroll in plcRemoteFormContainer when child content overflows.

All this requirement are meeting but when scroll is displaying, the child container is not filling the entire height of parent container.

This is the html code:
<div id="host">
  <div id="plc-remote-form">
    <div class="upperMenuContainer">Breadcrumb</div>

    <div class="plcRemoteFormContainer">
      <form id="plcRemoteForm">
        <fieldset class="identificationFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">identification</legend>
          <div class="identificationContainer">
            <div class="fieldForm idCard">
              <label for="idCard">Id Card*:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

And this is the css code:
#host {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 215px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 0.875rem !important;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#plc-remote-form {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;

  .upperMenuContainer {
    background-color: #0074c8;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 26px;
  }
}

.plcRemoteFormContainer {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

#plcRemoteForm {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

I have done a stackblitz to help to understand this problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/styles-form?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. How can I solve this problem? Thank you in advance.
I have trying set heigth:100% in child plcRemoteForm but this doesn't work.

Your form is fixed height due to other css you have added. You simply need to set the height of your #plcRemoteFrom as height:min-content; it will resize with the content and you will get the desired result i.e. no overflow on scroll.


#host {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 215px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 0.875rem !important;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding: 5px 10px 10px;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

#plc-remote-form {
  height: calc(100vh - 60px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
  .upperMenuContainer {
    background-color: #0074c8;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 26px;
  }
}

.plcRemoteFormContainer {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #c5c5c5;
}

#plcRemoteForm {
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  height:min-content;
}
<div id="host">
  <div id="plc-remote-form">
    <div class="upperMenuContainer">Breadcrumb</div>

    <div class="plcRemoteFormContainer">
      <form id="plcRemoteForm">
        <fieldset class="identificationFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">identification</legend>
          <div class="identificationContainer">
            <div class="fieldForm idCard">
              <label for="idCard">Id Card*:</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
          <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



There are other ways of doing this as well but this method is the simplest as per your code. If this doesn't suite your needs then let me know.

Well problem is here:
#plc-remote-form {
  **height: calc(100vh - 60px);**
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;

You must set 100vh to 100% so that it can take full height related to content not according to 100vh.

Hello Haddam, thank you for your answer. But it doesn't work.

Need to change CSS


#host {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-position: top;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100% 215px;
            overflow: auto;
            font-size: 0.875rem !important;
            line-height: 1.5;
            padding: 5px 10px 10px;
            background-color: #bbb;
        }

        #plc-remote-form {
            height: calc(100vh - 60px);
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: red;

            .upperMenuContainer {
                background-color: #0074c8;
                border-top-left-radius: 4px;
                border-top-right-radius: 4px;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 26px;
            }
        }

        .plcRemoteFormContainer {
            flex: 1;
            overflow-y: auto;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #c5c5c5;
        }

        #plcRemoteForm {
            background-color: #ebebeb;
            height: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
<div id="host">
        <div id="plc-remote-form">
            <div class="upperMenuContainer">Breadcrumb</div>

            <div class="plcRemoteFormContainer">
                <form id="plcRemoteForm">
                    <fieldset class="identificationFieldset">
                        <legend class="legend">identification</legend>
                        <div class="identificationContainer">
                            <div class="fieldForm idCard">
                                <label for="idCard">Id Card*:</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
                        <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
                        <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
                        <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
                        <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="electricalPanelDataFieldset">
                        <legend class="legend">electrical</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>




need to change css?? Please read on how to properly answer a question

Don't just post code. Explain what changes you have made, why and what difference it makes.

I need the scroll display in plcRemoteFormContainer container, not in plcRemoteForm. Is it possible or it's the only way?
